# REST API filter options in response body

Tags: rest, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to display the remaining possible filter options, for a REST endpoint, based on the already set filters.

Is there some kind of best practice, on how to design a REST API, to let the client know about the remaining options?

Something like this came to mind.

```
{
  "count": 131,
  "next": "2",
  "previous": null,
  "filters": {
    "status": [
      1,
      2,
      99
    ],
    "...": [
      "..."
    ]
  },
  "results": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "status": 1,
      "...": ".."
    },
    {
      "id": 1,
      "status": 2,
      "...": "...."
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to let the user know which filters can be added to an endpoint is to create an API Documentation with [Swagger](https://swagger.io/) or [Redoc](https://github.com/Redocly/redoc).

To let the clients know what filters they can add for an endpoint, you send them the documentation where they can see exactly how it can be used.

Do you have another particular use case for which you want to send them on the response?

If you must necessarily send the filters in the body, you can create a `FilterMixin` and put it on all the `ViewSets` where you want to have this functionality and overwrite the `list` function. An example would be somthing like this:

```
class FiltersMixin:
    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        data = super().list(request, *args, **kwargs)
        remaining_filters = list(set(self.filter_fields) - set(self.request.query_params.keys())
        return {"filters": remaining_filters, **data}
```

This works if the filters on the viewset are added on the `ViewSet` using the `filter_fields` property.

Comment: Sorry if my question was unclear, but I'm looking for something different. For Example: you have two filters 'brands' and 'categories'. Now based on the selected category only the corresponding brands should be available to filter.

Comment: @TimPossible can you please edit your question if possible.